How to expose rabbitmq port 5671 as TCP (not HTTP/HTTPS) in Nginx Ingress
I have deployed Rabbitmq statefulset inside my EKS cluster pod is up and running and also i can able to perform the port forwarding to test the rabbitmq UI page service connection using localhost:port number.
To achieve TCP port expose i have created configmap in default namespace where my Rabbitmq pod is running.
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: tcp-services
data:
  5672: "default/rabbitmq-service:5672"

Followed by above configmap i have created Rabbitmq services as a clusterIP services
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
  labels:
    app: rabbitmq
spec:
  selector:
    app: rabbitmq
  ports:
   - name: http
     protocol: TCP
     port: 15672
     targetPort: 15672
   - name: amqp
     protocol: TCP
     port: 5672
     targetPort: 5672
   - name: amqps
     protocol: TCP
     port: 5671
     targetPort: 5671 


Finally nginx ingress yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
  name: rabbit-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host:my-host.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: rabbitmq
                port:
                  number: 5672
            path: /
            pathType: Prefix

How to test and validate the TCP connection port connection after all the configuration which applied.

From the official Kubernetes documentation

An Ingress does not expose arbitrary ports or protocols. Exposing services other than HTTP and HTTPS to the internet typically uses a service of type Service.Type=NodePort or Service.Type=LoadBalancer.

As well a service of type ClusterIP can't be used, because this type of service is only for cluster-local loadbalancing.

In Kubernetes, Services are an abstract way to expose an application running on a set of Pods. Services can have a cluster-scoped virtual IP address (using a Service of type: ClusterIP).

So you could use a service of type LoadBalancer for example
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - appProtocol: amqps
      name: amqps
      port: 5671
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 5671
  selector:
    app: rabbitmq


Hi @JGK thanks for the quick response. But if you see my service file i didn't mentioned any service type which means by default it will create clusterIP.

Please see my enhanced answer about service types.
